# How do I properly comment a variable definition in GNU Make?

Tags: string, replace, comments, gnu-make

So I want to comment variable definitions in Makefile in-line. The problem is that Make doesn't strip white spaces between the definition and its comment. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
OPTS += -DBLA       # Does bla
OPTS += -DBLUBB     # Does blubb
OPTS += -DEND

.PHONY test
test:
    @echo $(OPTS)
```

The output of this is

```
-DBLA       -DBLUBB     -DEND
```

with annoying extra white spaces between the options. What I want is this:

```
-DBLA -DBLUBB -DEND
```

How do I get around this Problem? The Make string function `@echo $(strip $(OPTS))` would only strip whitespaces after `-DEND` or before `-DBLA`, not inbetween. My dirty hack so far is `@echo $(shell $(OPTS))`, which strips the unwanted spaces but uses a shell call to do so, that probably will introduce other problems, i.e. unwanted shell injection via the `$(OPTS)` variable. Is there a better way to do it? Simple `@echo ($subst ...)` doesn't work on mixed whitespaces unless one replaces all of them an then reinserts at the `-`.

Comment: Put the comments on the line above the assignment? Deal with the harmless extra space in the command being run (the shell is going to immediately throw it away anyway)?

Comment: The line above would be the obvious choice, but I don't want the comments on a different line, period. It bloats the Makefile and makes it less readable. Yes, the shell is going to throw them away. Before that, however, they create some problems in my IDE. The IDE incorporates calls to Make.

Comment: Sounds like your IDE needs to get fixed then and you have flatly rejected the only solution. Good luck. (For the record over-commenting makes makefiles **impossible** to read in my experience, at least when coming in new.)

Comment: Not if you only explain options at the very beginning, but okay, if you have it all figured out.

Comment: "only explain options at the very beginning" sounds a lot like "on the line above" to me which you rejected. And yes, even just a single line comment above each line makes makefiles *very* hard to process I find. See the makefiles in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31609667/258523) for example.

Comment: Also `$(strip)` does compress internal whitespace according to [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-stripping-whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

```
OPTS += -DBLA#     Does bla
OPTS += -DBLUBB#   Does blubb
OPTS += -DEND
```

Canonical *make*?
Not a fan of alignment though.

```
OPTS += -DBLA# Does bla
OPTS += -DBLUBB# Does blubb
OPTS += -DEND
```

Looks better to my eyes.

Assuming it makes your eyes bleed,
`$(strip)` does in fact do what you want.

```
OPTS := $(strip ${OPTS})
```

A simple `$(error [${OPTS}])` will prove it.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Of course, 'zZz' could be replaced with any "impossible" match...