# C++ Makefile error - No rule to make target '%.cpp'

Tags: c++, makefile

Good day, I am running through a tutorial to write my own makefiles, I found the tutorial here:

http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

I know this tutorial is for C makefiles, however I believe that the similiarities between C and C++ would mean there is little difference in how the makefiles function (for instance, I am using g++ rather than gcc). I hope my assumption on this point isn't a factor, since each of the previous 4 tutorials appear to have worked just fine.

When running through Makefile 5 in the tutorial, I am getting an error regarding the construction of the object files from the .cpp files:

`make: *** No rule to make target '%.cpp', needed by 'obj'. Stop.`

I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening, very confusing and frustrating as I feel like this shouldn't be happening. I include my full Makefile below, any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

```
 # Example Makefile                                                                                                                                                                                             
 # ----------------
 # Please remember to turn off the vim option: 'expandtab' so that tabs are 
 # actually displayed as tabs (do so like this - :set noexpandtab )
 #

 # This file specifies dependencies, which means that the two c++ files must
 # be compiled before the executable is built

 # ------------------
 # Makefile Constants
 # ------------------

 # Directory constants
 IDIR =../include  # Specifies location of include directory
 ODIR =obj        # Specifies location of object directory
 LDIR =../lib      # Specifies location of library directory

 LIBS=-lm  # ?

 # Options constants
 CC=g++            # Specifies the specific C compiler to use, g++ specifies C++ compiler
 CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)  # List of flags to pass to compilation command

 # Dependency Constants
 DEP_FILES=helloMake.h                      # Specifies dependency files
 DEPS=$(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(DEP_FILES))  # Specifies path to dependencies and dependency files

 # Object constants
 OBJ_FILES=helloMake.o helloFunc.o         # Specify object files
 OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(OBJ_FILES))  # Specifies path to objects and object files


 # -----------
 # Compilation
 # -----------

 # Specify rules to make object files
 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)       # Specifies that .o files depend on the .cpp version of the file and the .h files included in the DEPS macro
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)  # The -c flag says to generate the object file, the -o $@ says to put the output of the compilation in the
                                  # file named on the left side of the : the $< is the first item in the dependencies list

 # Specify rules to make target executable
 helloMake: $(OBJ)                     # Target : Dependencies
     $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)  # This is the actual compilation command

 .PHONY: clean  # Prevent the make command from attempting to do something with a file named 'clean'

 # Specify rules to clean the object files
 clean:
     rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~  # Removes all compiled object files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "simple" tutorial unfortunately promotes bad practices.

Basically, you first need a correct C Makefile:

```make
# Specify the final target name
EXE := helloMake

# Specify the source files
# Effectively list all source files in the current directory
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)

# From the source file list, get the corresponding object file list
# This is a clearer syntax for $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)

# From the object file list, get the dependency file list to handle automatic
# recompilation when a header file is modified
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

# Specify preprocessor flags (this is a built-in variable)
CPPFLAGS := -I../include
# Required flags to enable the automatic dependency generation by the compiler
CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP

# Specify compiler flags (this is a built-in variable)
# Here some basic warning flags
CFLAGS := -Wall -W -pedantic

# Specify linker flags (this is a built-in variable)
LDFLAGS := -L../lib

# Specify linker libraries (this is a built-in variable)
# m is the maths library
LDLIBS := -lm

# Tell make that these target are not real files
.PHONY: all clean

# Now the standard primary rule
all: $(EXE)

# How do we make $(EXE) ? Remember the recipe describe the linking phase
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# Let's clean up the mess
clean:
    $(RM) $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(DEP)

# Don't forget to include the dependency files to let make know when to recompile
-include $(DEP)
```

Then you need to know the difference between a C Makefile and a C++ Makefile:

- Use `$(CXX)` instead of `$(CC)`,
- Use `$(CXXFLAGS)` instead of `$(CFLAGS)`,
- Use `.cpp` instead of `.c`.

And you're done.

```make
# Specify the final target name
EXE := helloMake

# Specify the source files
# Effectively list all source files in the current directory
SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)

# From the source file list, get the corresponding object file list
# This is a clearer syntax for $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))
OBJ := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

# From the object file list, get the dependency file list to handle automatic
# recompilation when a header file is modified
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

# Specify preprocessor flags (this is a built-in variable)
CPPFLAGS := -I../include
# Required flags to enable the automatic dependency generation by the compiler
CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP

# Specify compiler flags (this is a built-in variable)
# Here some basic warning flags
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -W -pedantic

# Specify linker flags (this is a built-in variable)
LDFLAGS := -L../lib

# Specify linker libraries (this is a built-in variable)
# m is the maths library
LDLIBS := -lm

# Tell make that these target are not real files
.PHONY: all clean

# Now the standard primary rule
all: $(EXE)

# How do we make $(EXE) ? Remember the recipe describe the linking phase
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# Let's clean up the mess
clean:
    $(RM) $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(DEP)

# Don't forget to include the dependency files to let make know when to recompile
-include $(DEP)
```

---

Edit: To be able to relocate the build files (`.o` and `.d` files), you need a few adjustments:

```make
# Specify the final target name
EXE := helloMake

# Specify the source files
# Effectively list all source files in the current directory
SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)

# Specify where to put the build temporary files
BLD := obj

# From the source file list, get the corresponding object file list
# This is a clearer syntax for $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BLD)/%.o,$(SRC))
OBJ := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(BLD)/%.o)

# From the object file list, get the dependency file list to handle automatic
# recompilation when a header file is modified
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

# Specify preprocessor flags (this is a built-in variable)
CPPFLAGS := -I../include
# Required flags to enable the automatic dependency generation by the compiler
CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP

# Specify compiler flags (this is a built-in variable)
# Here some basic warning flags
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -W -pedantic

# Specify linker flags (this is a built-in variable)
LDFLAGS := -L../lib

# Specify linker libraries (this is a built-in variable)
# m is the maths library
LDLIBS := -lm

# Tell make that these target are not real files
.PHONY: all clean

# Now the standard primary rule
all: $(EXE)

# How do we make $(EXE) ? Remember the recipe describe the linking phase
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# The build directory is custom so we need to tell make how to do it
# The build directory must exist before trying to compile
$(BLD)/%.o: %.cpp | $(BLD)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# Simple rule to create the build directory if needed
$(BLD):
    mkdir $@

# Let's clean up the mess, we can just remove the build directory alonside the executable
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BLD) $(EXE)

# Don't forget to include the dependency files to let make know when to recompile
-include $(DEP)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I have tried the Makefile you have suggested however when I try to make it I now get a different error: g++: error: arm-linux-androideabi: No such file or directory

Comment: It seems your compiler setup isn't correct, what is your environment (OS, compiler version, make version) ?

Comment: OS: Linux (Using VMWare vSphere Client Virtual Machine)
Compiler version: g++ (GCC) 4.9.3 20141101 for GNAT Pro 7.3.1 (20150118)
make version: Not entireyl sure what you mean tbh!

Comment: Hm I don't know about that GNAT Pro version of GCC ... Could you post the entire make output by editing your question ? What I mean is that something is wrong on your side because the makefile I wrote here is fully functional and tested.

Comment: I've tried several times to post my error but stack overflow doesn't seem to want to let me for some reason...

Please find the full error below:

g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -I../include -MMD -MP arm-linux-androideabi -c -o helloFunc.o helloFunc.cpp
g++: error: arm-linux-androideabi: No such file or directory
make: *** [helloFunc.o] Error 1

Comment: Ok I think I know. You can try my edit, or simply add `undefine TARGET_ARCH` to your makefile above the `.PHONY` special rule.

Comment: You are a star! This works excellently now, many many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `%` syntax is not standard `make` but an extended feature provided by e.g. `GNU make` (otherwise, you'd have to write particular rules for every source file or use something like the `autotools` that generate *huge* (but portable) `Makefile`s). So, you should make sure you're using a `make` utility supporting this. If that's not the problem, are you sure you actually HAVE `*.cpp` files in your current directory?

Comment: I do indeed have the .cpp files in the correct directory, I also ensured to put my .h file in the inlcude directory. I'm starting to think the tutorial web page I used may not have been the best thing for me to use...

Comment: Do you have any examples of any make implementations in common usage where pattern rules  (`%` syntax) are not supported?

Comment: E.g. `nmake` doesn't support this and has as a replacement the less flexible *inference rules*.